# Plotting tolerance bars in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have existing code which reduces to this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ref = [(0.0, 151.6875), (0.011, 151.75), (0.022, 151.75), (0.031, 151.625), (0.042, 151.625), (0.052, 151.6875), (0.061, 151.625), (0.073, 151.6875), (0.08, 151.625)]
res = [(0.0, 151.879), (0.01, 151.881), (0.02, 151.882), (0.03, 151.884), (0.04, 151.886), (0.05, 151.887), (0.06, 151.889), (0.07, 151.891), (0.08, 151.892)]

plt.plot(*zip(*res), 'g')
plt.plot(*zip(*ref), 'b')

plt.show()
```

Unfortunatley, I don't understand pyton well enough to inderstand the starred expression or the `zip` function, but it appears to group X values into a tuple and Y values into a tuple.

I'd like to add 10% tolerance lines around `ref`. I know this should work:

```
plt.fill_between(x, y * 0.9, y * 1.1)
```

but I can't figure out how to translate ref and res into x,  and y.  I've tried:

```
ref_x, ref_y = zip(*ref)
plt.fill_between(ref_x, ref_y * 0.9, ref_y * 1.1)
```

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

And I've tried this:

```
for point in ref :
    plt.fill_between(point[0], point[1] * 0.9, point[1] * 1.1)
```

> TypeError: len() of unsized object

How can I translate `ref` into something that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ref_y`; it's a list. To multiply a list by a constant in pure python you would need to multiply each element of that list with that constant,  `new_data = [x*0.9 for x in old_data]`.

The much easier solution is to work with numpy arrays right away.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ref = [(0.0, 151.6875), (0.011, 151.75), (0.022, 151.75), (0.031, 151.625), (0.042, 151.625), (0.052, 151.6875), (0.061, 151.625), (0.073, 151.6875), (0.08, 151.625)]
res = [(0.0, 151.879), (0.01, 151.881), (0.02, 151.882), (0.03, 151.884), (0.04, 151.886), (0.05, 151.887), (0.06, 151.889), (0.07, 151.891), (0.08, 151.892)]

ref = np.array(ref)
res = np.array(res)

plt.plot(ref[:,0], ref[:,1], 'g')
plt.plot(res[:,0], ref[:,1], 'b')

plt.fill_between(ref[:,0], ref[:,1] * 0.9, ref[:,1] * 1.1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Our timings were perfectly synchronized ;) btw I realized you have an `import` in your username

Comment: Yeah, I'll usually do `import anceOfBeingErnst as me` every moring. :-P

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions in my opinion:

First, create two lists as the upper and lower bounds and use `fill_between`. The reason you can't multiply directly by 0.9 and 1.1 is because `zip` returns `tuple`. Even if you convert it to a list using `list(ref_y)`, you can't multiply each element of a list by an integer/float all at once unlike with arrays:

```
lim_down = [0.9*i for i in ref_y]
lim_up = [1.1*i for i in ref_y]
plt.fill_between(ref_x, lim_down, lim_up)
```

Second, you convert your y-values to arrays which allows you to simply multiply them by 0.9 and 1.1 which will be applied to each element.

```
plt.fill_between(ref_x, np.array(ref_y) * 0.9, np.array(ref_y) * 1.1)
```

Output (The res is now covered by your error bars/filled region because 10% seems to be too much in this case.):

[image]